# SharePoint - KQL - Department property contains value

Tags: sharepoint

Requirement: I do have "People search" webpart and I need to return ONLY users with a value associated to Department property.

Additional comments:
If in the SharePoint User Profile, the department property does not hold any value, I don't need to return this specific user.

I expected to have this one (below) working but it still returns users with no values associated to the Department property

{searchboxquery}* Department<>""

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't filter based on empty value directly, you could check the 'workaround' [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162369/how-to-build-search-query-to-filter-data-based-on-null-value).

```
Department:a* 
Department:b* 
Department:c* 
Department:d* 
Department:e* 
Department:f* 
Department:g* 
Department:h* 
Department:i* 
Department:h* 
Department:k* 
Department:l* 
Department:m* 
Department:n* 
Department:o* 
Department:p* 
Department:q* 
Department:r* 
Department:s* 
Department:t* 
Department:u* 
Department:v* 
Department:w* 
Department:x* 
Department:y* 
Department:z*
```